# facet like functionality in NoSQL systems

Tags: solr, nosql, facet, faceted-search

Does anyone know / can someone point to an nosql db, which would support faceting, like in Apache SOLR, off the shelf?

I have read, that in Sphinx they don't support facet search out of the box, but one can implement it in a form of plugin.

Upd: I'm only interested in enterprise level systems.

Answer (score 0):

CouchDB (Eearlang) and RavenDB (.NET) both are based on Lucene, so it should be possible to make them both support Faceted Search. RavenDB already partially supports that.

And Sphinx isn't a NoSQL DB.

Comment: facet is the pure SOLR feature, so implementing it from scratch in these Lucene based engines will turn into implementing SOLR.

Comment: http://sphinxsearch.com/about/sphinx/ it can access data in SQL DBs and it exposes SphinxQL, SphinxAPI, which pretty much suggest it is nosql system.

Comment: As the page you linked to states explicitly, Sphinx is a "search server". In other words: its a competitor to Lucene/Solr. I'm not sure how you derived from the fact it offers its own SQL-like query-language that it is a NoSQL system, but its most definitely not - just like it isn't an RDBMS. Just like you can't call Oracle a search-server just because it has Oracle Text available.

Comment: Faceted search is a concept implemented into Solr, and implementing that from scratch using bare Lucene isn't too much of a job given you know your way around it. And the fact is most of the word is already done for you. See http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2007/01/faceted-searching-with-lucene.html, http://www.devatwork.nl/articles/lucenenet/faceted-search-and-drill-down-lucenenet/, http://code.google.com/p/bobo-browse/, https://github.com/mattwarren/ravendb-FacetedSearch

Comment: @synhershko: on sphynx thread: I wonder, how do you define nosql. In any case I didn't mean to argue about which category sphinx should be classified to. Moreover, I am not even familiar with the system.

Comment: @synhershko: on the facet in SOLR: implementing it from scratch isn't an option for me now. But thanks for the links, they look promising.

Comment: Let's start by agreeing that for a product to be of the NoSQL kind, it needs to be a database. Sphinx and Lucene both are NOT a database... If you're using Java Lucene, Bobo Search should give you all that you need. If you use RavenDB, Faceted search should be supported in a short while.

Comment: @synhershko, ok, I'm curious: when you say "a database", what do you mean?

Comment: Database is a place where you go and store data for retrieving it later. Its THE place where you data resides, and nowadays NoSQL are popular because it allows you to save OOPish data as-is without flattening it and all that. Lucene/Solr and Sphinx for example are not meant to be that. They are meant to be efficient search engines you feed your data (which is stored in your DB) to provide full-text search DBs don't support well.

Answer (score 0):

Turnes out, that sphinx does have facetted search feature. It has similar features of a "linguistic" pipeline, distributed search, tokenization etc as the ones in Apache SOLR/Lucene. It is an interesting option to Apache SOLR in the sense, that it is written in C++, yet is language independent on client side, same way as SOLR. It is OS as SOLR/Lucene, so customizing code is possible.